# Toast popup for dynamic type

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility, dynamic-type-feature

I've noticed that when you turn on dynamic type, there are apps such as Settings that will display a toast message with the text of certain controls when you hold a finger on the control. Does anyone know if this is built in functionality or do I have to build my own version? If it is built in, how do I turn it on?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if this is built in functionality or do I have to build my own version?

Exactly like `Dynamic Type`, some graphical items have a scalable size thanks to accessibility settings but **only since iOS11**: a very interesting **built-in feature** called the **Large Content Viewer**.

> If it is built in, how do I turn it on?

Some [steps](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#graphical-elements-size) have to be followed in Xcode to reach your goal *(image with a `pdf` extension, resizing, scales, adjusts image Size...)*: check out the provided link to get a complete example.

If you need further explanation:

- This WWDC [detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html) dives deeper into explanations for the `Dynamic Type` feature implementation *(see the example section on the web page of the link)*.
- This WWDC [detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-19261.html) introduces the `Large Content Viewer` feature that can be adapted to custom views since iOS 13.